# Mouse position in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, mouse, bind

I am trying to get the mouse position relative to a tkinter window. The problem is when I am with the mouse inside of a label or a button, because it gives me the position relative to that label or button. I want the coordinates to be ralated only for my window not the other widgets.
Here is a piece of my code where I have the problem.

Bind the button:

```
select.bind('<Motion>', motion)
select.bind('<Any-Button>', on_click)
```

Functions to detect mouse position and when it is clicked:

```
def on_click(event):
    if event.num == 1:
        print(x_mouse, y_mouse)
```

```
def motion(event):
    global x_mouse, y_mouse
    x_mouse, y_mouse = event.x, event.y
```

Comment: Have you looked at all of the data that is available in the `event` object? Do the `x_root` and `y_root` attributes solve your problem?

Comment: Yes sir, thank you !